# React Need to toggle a div when an edit is clicked for one object in json array(open/Close)

Tags: reactjs

I have a json array and i am iterating array and show the list ,each have its own id.
Each having edit button and when you click on edit ,it shoudl show a div ,inside div i have a dummy text,like wise when i click the edit of next object from JSON array,already openend div of previous object should close and the new JSON object edit div should toggle

```
<div>
              <li key={contact.id}>
                <p>{contact.firstName} {contact.lastName}</p>
                <p>{contact.email}</p>
                <button onClick={() => this.removeContact(contact.id)}>Remove</button>
                <button onClick={() => this.showEditDiv(contact.id)}>Edit</button>
                <div className="">
                  <p>This is edit form</p>
                </div>
              </li>
            </div>
```

Any live demo or jsfiddle will be highly grateful and appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  const [activeCurrentDiv, setActiveCurrentDiv] = useState(null);

  const [list, setList] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      firstName: "john",
      email: "sample1@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      firstName: "harry",
      email: "sampleharry@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      firstName: "halk",
      email: "spiderman@gmail.com"
    }
  ]);

  const removeContact = id => {
    const filteredList = list.filter(item => {
      return item.id !== id;
    });
    setList(filteredList);
  };

  const showEditDiv = id => {
    setActiveCurrentDiv(id);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {list.map((contact, key) => {
          return (
            <li key={contact.id}>
              <p>
                {contact.firstName} {contact.lastName}
              </p>
              <p>{contact.email}</p>
              <button onClick={() => removeContact(contact.id)}>Remove</button>
              <button onClick={() => showEditDiv(contact.id)}>Edit</button>
              <div className={(activeCurrentDiv === contact.id ? "show" : "") + " myDiv"}>
                <p>This is edit form</p>
              </div>
            </li>
          );
        })}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}


ul {
  list-style: none;
}

ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #eaeaea;
}

.myDiv {
  display: none;
}

.myDiv.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

You can use "contant.id" and check if it is equals to the "current_id" in my case "activeCurrentDiv" it's time to show that div.

and each user clicks on Edit u save the "current_id/activeCurrentDiv"

working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-sound-t9t5r

Answer (score 1):

[Live example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/focused-shadow-jl84m)

Code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    email: "asf@asdf.com",
    firstName: "Anna",
    lastName: "L name"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    email: "asf1@asdf.com",
    firstName: "Jan",
    lastName: "L name 2"
  }
];
function App() {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = React.useState<number[]>([]);

  const showEditDiv = (id: number) => {
    if(isOpen.includes(id)) {
      setIsOpen([...isOpen.filter(listId => listId !== id )]);
      return;
    }
    setIsOpen([...isOpen, id]);
  };

  const removeContact = (id: number) => {}


  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {data.map(contact => (
          <div>
            <li key={contact.id}>
              <p>
                {contact.firstName} {contact.lastName}
              </p>
              <p>{contact.email}</p>
              <button onClick={() => removeContact(contact.id)}>
                Remove
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => showEditDiv(contact.id)}>Edit</button>
              {isOpen.includes(contact.id) && (
                <div>
                  <p>This is edit form</p>
                </div>
              )}
            </li>
          </div>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
render(<App />, rootElement);
```